# Windows Live Messenger Can't Login, Error 8100030d

Tags: windows, windows-live-messenger

Just recently my Windows Live Messenger started not logging in. Running version WLM 2011, Build 15.4.3508.1109

I have tried most things I have found on the internet to help but still doesnt work. I can login to WLM with another account so it seems my account might be messed up but I am not sure. Also, the web based WLM in hotmail and on live.com doesn't work for me. Any suggestions or fixes?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Also, the web based WLM in hotmail and on live.com doesn't work for me."? What happens when you try to log into login.live.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this just resolved itself after a few reboots.